# Integration constants in the brachistrochone problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates, optimal-control

Let see the solution presented at

http://www.math.utk.edu/~freire/teaching/m231f08/m231f08brachistochrone.pdf

Page 4, he has 3 integrations constants : $C, x_{\phi_0}$ and $y_{\phi_0}$
to integrate $x(\phi),y(\phi)$.

He set $x_{\phi_0}=0$ and $y_{\phi_0}=C\,/\,2$ but I don't understand its explanatation that is :

> $x=0$ corresponds to $y=0$ hence $\phi=0$.

It seems he imposes that $\phi(0)=0$ which should be proved ?

Comment: Can be done much simpler by writing down the Hamiltonian and using that this is conserved. The Lagrangian is $$L = \sqrt{\frac{1+y'^2}{y}}$$, the canonical momentum is: $$p = \frac{\partial L}{\partial y'} = \frac{y'^2}{\sqrt{y}\sqrt{1+y'^2}}$$ and the Hamiltonian (in terms of $y$ and $y'$) is: $$H = p y' -  L = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}\sqrt{1+y'^2}}$$, and this is then a conserved quantity because it doesn't depend explicitly in the integration variable (analogous to why in physics energy is conserved when the Hamiltonian doesn't depend on time). We the get $$y'^2 - \frac{k}{y} = -1$$

Comment: This is the equation for one dimensional motion of a particle in a gravitational potential.